# Is there a standard for text justification?

Tags: unicode, justify

I'm finding a reference for justifying text in Unicode. I was thinking about [UAX#14](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/) or [UAX#29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/), but none of them seems to have exactly proper behavior for justifying.

In English, this is basically splitting the text by whitespace and position them to have equally wide space between them. I'm wondering what are the guidelines for other language, preferably with some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justification is a complex problem, and is highly language dependent, and even for the same language may differ depending on eg vertical vs. horizontal writing in Japanese. Each typesetting system (of which HTML can be considered one) implements its own more or (often) less sophisticated solution. For more information, consult https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-archive/2016Aug/att-0004/text-justify-i18n.html.

> In English, this is basically splitting the text by whitespace and position them to have equally wide space between them. I'm wondering what are the guidelines for other language, preferably with some references.

Not really. For example, I may also want to insert micro-spacing between letters. However, this should be avoided in the case of German, for example, since spaced-out letters are sometimes used for emphasis in that language. More basically, even in English a different amount of space could and should be inserted between words and between sentences, etc.

You can find a more recent reference [here](https://www.w3.org/International/talks/1703-jleq/).